# SAXparser android XML feed trouble

Tags: java, android, xml, rss, sax

I have a very similar problem to the following issue. Unfortunately I have not found my answer after reading through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18199289/saxparser-android-arraylist-repeating-elements).

I am trying to gather an RSS feed from my website for my android app. I am using the following java script to do so.

```
 public class XMLHelper extends DefaultHandler {

private String URL_MAIN = "http://**.**.***.***/blank/blank/feed/?format=xml";
String TAG = "XMLHelper";

Boolean currTag = false;
String currTagVal = "";
public ItemValue post = null;
public ArrayList<ItemValue> posts = new ArrayList<ItemValue>();


public void get() {
    try {
        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser mSaxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader mXmlReader = mSaxParser.getXMLReader();
        mXmlReader.setContentHandler(this);
        InputStream mInputStream = new URL(URL_MAIN).openStream();
        mXmlReader.parse(new InputSource(mInputStream));
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {
    if(currTag) {
        currTagVal = currTagVal + new String(ch, start, length);
        currTag = false;
    }
}


@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {
    currTag = false;

    if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("title"))
        post.setTitle(currTagVal);

    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
        posts.add(post);
    }
}

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
                         Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    Log.i(TAG, "TAG: " + localName);

    currTag = true;
    currTagVal = "";

    if(localName.equals("item"))
        post = new ItemValue();
}
```

This is pulling from the following xml.

```
 <channel>
<title>Welcome to my website</title>
<link>http://**.**.***.***/blank/blank/feed</link>
<atom:link href="http://**.**.***.***/blank/blank/feed/?format=xml" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml"/>
<description>Activity feed</description>
<lastBuildDate>Wed, 15 Apr 2015 16:21:17 +0000</lastBuildDate>
<generator>http://buddypress.org/?v=2.2.1</generator>
<language>en-US</language>
<ttl>30</ttl>
<sy:updatePeriod>hourly</sy:updatePeriod>
<sy:updateFrequency>2</sy:updateFrequency>
<item>
<guid isPermaLink="false">822b2a07599526230c7bae1b1d0a00bf</guid>
<title>
gordy77 posted an update in the group ****, **: Now the magic begins
</title>
<link>http://**.**.***.***/draft-2/p/9/</link>
<pubDate>Mon, 13 Apr 2015 16:47:29 +0000</pubDate>
<content:encoded>...</content:encoded>
<slash:comments>0</slash:comments>
</item>
```

Now when I run the app I just get a blank screen and the following error.

```
E/XMLHelper﹕ Exception: null
```

By changing the following code I can get the app to run but it only pulls one comment "item" from the RSS feed and repeats it 3 times. It is always the first "item" posted on that feed x3.

```
if(localName.equals("item"))
        post = new ItemValue();

if(localName.equals("channel"))
        post = new ItemValue();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code:

```
 if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("title"))
        post.setTitle(currTagVal);
```

Check if `post is null`, since the tag `title` can also appear outside a post

example:

```
 if(null != post && localName.equalsIgnoreCase("title"))
        post.setTitle(currTagVal);
```